# calling a scene in cocos2d is fire init method?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i use cocos2d in xcode.
when i call from xcode class to a cocos  class(scene) function, it fires the init method, BUT i want to fire only the spesific function that i call, because the init was already fired at the start of the animation ...

how to do that ?

```
HelloWorld *ran=[[HelloWorld alloc] init];
    [ran HardwareEvent:DollPart];
```

the cocos2d class name that i call is  is HelloWorldScene.
how can i call a function and not fire init ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already called init on HelloWorld from withing your current scene.  If that's the case then I'd create a variable in the .h to access HelloWorld throughout your current scene.  In your .h it would look something like:

```
HelloWorld *helloWorld
```

This would change the other time that you called init on your HelloWorld scene to just be

```
helloWorld = [[HelloWorld alloc] init];
```

and should allow you to call the HardwareEvent: DollPart: method by just calling

```
[helloWorld HardwareEvent:DollPart];
```

Comment: @Rant So you created the variable for your whole class? Because `HelloWorld *ran=[[HelloWorld alloc] init];
    [ran HardwareEvent:DollPart];` isn't doing that.  If that's what you did then you should be able to just take the name of the variable you created and call your method using it.

Comment: I am not sure you understood me , i want to call from a regular class to cocos2d class. Yes i have put the HelloWorld *ran; in the regular class .h file and then i alloc it and called the function in the cocos2d class. whats happen is that the init is been called, and my cocos2d animation is not working. does its something about layers?